# how do i make a function that compares its arguments in python

Tags: python, function, compare

I am trying to make a function that takes its arguments and compares them, returning true if they are the same. I have this code but it keeps telling me I have an invalid syntax for the first argument. what do I have wrong?

```
    def PnUcompare(X,Y):
        if X == Y:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Looks good to me (assuming the over-indentation is a SO formatting issue, and not how your code actually looks). Can you please share the exact text of the error you're getting?

Comment: please post the full traceback, there seem to be no syntax errors here.

Comment: Why is this not just `return X == Y`?

Comment: Turns out it was just a silly over-indentation. Thanks for the help guys.